# SQL Server: how to avoid sysadmin rights but give adequate rights

Tags: sql-server, security

I have a collegue who want to get an access to one SQL Server 2008 instance. I'll have to give him rights to this instance. He should have rights to do is e.g.

- Add and modify server logins
- Add and modify maintenanace plans (e.g. create backups from the databases)
- Schedule Agent jobs

I don't want to give him sysadmin rights, what rights should be given?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For server logins, you can grant ["securityadmin"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189610%28SQL.90%29.aspx). The "newer" way is to run

```
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO AColleague
```

Edit: Securityadmin allows someone to bootstrap themselves to sysadmin. Not good. Don't know how to workaround this at the server level

For jobs, look at the ["SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx)

For maintenance plans, it looks [like "sysadmin" only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189036%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it says in BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx?ppud=4 that securityadmin should be treated as sysadmin server role. Is there a way to narrow securityadmin rights to logins? Or will that "GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN to AColleagu" do that?

Comment: @jrara: securityadmin is enough or the GRANT

Comment: It should be treated as sysadmin because giving securityadmin rights allows the user to grant himself/herself sysadmin role permissions.

Comment: @jrara: in which case, you can't use securityadmin. In the db% roles, principals and permissions are separated. It's usual to not grant any server roles except maybe bulkadmin

Answer (score 5):

Just so you have something to look forward to, in SQL Server Denali this will be even more flexible. Instead of granting individual rights one-by-one, you'll be able to define [custom server roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677610%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), assign all those permissions to the role, then add members to the role. Some folks have blogged about it:

http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/customserverrolesindenali

http://www.straightpathsql.com/archives/2010/11/create-your-own-sql-server-server-roles/