# Can I delegate SQL Agent rights without granting sysadmin rights?

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, sql-server-agent

I'd like to give a user the ability to administer SQL Agent jobs.  According to [the doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), I can do this by granting the "appropriate" roles on msdb.  I've granted all three SQLAgent% roles, but the user gets this error when (as a test) trying to rename a job:

```
Only members of sysadmin role are allowed to update or delete jobs owned by a different login.
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14525)
```

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5022/sql-server-how-to-avoid-sysadmin-rights-but-give-adequate-rights) is similar, but no answer there addresses SQL Agent.  Is the sysadmin role the only solution, in MS SQL 2K8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, administration of Agent jobs can currently only be done by members of the `sysadmin` role.  The relevant documentation is found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx).  You'll note that the three Agent roles (User, Reader, and Operator) have different levels, but ultimately a user without `sysadmin` can only edit/manage jobs that user owns and not jobs created by other users.

Comment: Sad panda.  Your link is the 2012 version of the page I linked earlier; neither, however, seems to say anything  about only `sysadmin` users being able to edit others' jobs.  Unless I missed it?

Comment: You can look at the older versions from the "Other versions" drop down, but there isn't much that has changed.  It doesn't explicitly say only needing `sysadmin`, but all the documentation shows that the Agent roles you can grant only allow editing of jobs owned by the login.  It's declared by its absence.

Answer (score 3):

It can by done by overriding of sp_update_job procedure.
Steps described here: http://borishristov.com/blog/modifying-not-owned-sql-agent-jobs-without-being-a-sysadmin/

Comment: It's 2022 and there still isn't a way to do this.  Maybe the article you posted offered a workaround but unfortunately, the link no longer works. In the future, please post the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles says "A user must be a member of one of these fixed database roles **or** a member of the sysadmin fixed server role to use SQL Server Agent." (emphasis mine)

So you SHOULD not need to be a member of the sysadmin role to see SQL Server Agent, which contradicts what Mike Fal said above. Maybe it's a SQL Server or SSMS bug...

Comment: No, Mike Fal said that users with the other roles, but without `sysadmin`, cannot *change or delete jobs they don't own*. He didn't say they couldn't "see SQL Server Agent", and that's not what this question was about.